# Spring Aspect - How to make my custom aspect have access to method arguments through Spring EL?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-aop

I want to have access to method arguments through EL just like how PreAuthorize is having access to method arguments it is applied on.

Example:

```
@PreAuthorize("#contact.name == authentication.name")
public void doSomething(Contact contact);
```

I want to do similar thing for my custom aspect

```
 @MyAspect("#contact.name")
 public void doSomething(Contact contact);
```

Is there a way I could do it via Spring AOP?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [code of @PreAuthorize](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/3.0.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/access/prepost/PreAuthorize.java), there should be only a `value()` attribute in the annotation. This should get an EL expression.

And then, you can see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) about how you can parse EL expressions.